# UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UITableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, scroll, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UITableView` where in each row an `UIImage` is added with `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. Now I have the issue, when touching the imageView, the code for the gestureRecognizer is performed. But when I move the finger up/down the table view does not scroll.

This is clear, as the touch is still inside the gestureRecognizer.

Is there a way how I can get the tableView scrolling in my gestureRecognizer? That is, when I am in the gestureRecognizer and the finger moves up, than I call the tableView Scrolling methode?

Comment: `yourLongPressGestureRecognizer.allowableMovement = 0` and you should implement delegate method like this: `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}`

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be usefull to you

```
     UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                                                   initWithTarget:self
                                                                   action:@selector(handleLongPress:)];
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 1.0;
    [cell addGestureRecognizer:longPress];

  -  (void)handleLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender {
        CGPoint location = [sender locationInView:yourtableviewobj];
        //Get the corresponding index path within the table view
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tablechat indexPathForRowAtPoint:location];
        if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
      }
        else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan){
       }
    }
```

Comment: Was helpfull for testing another tableview-problem :)